# Integrating letter_opener with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am currently using the Devise gem for authentication with my rails app and I am having trouble using the [letter_opener](https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener) gem with it.  I can get it to work with a the standard mailer but I'm not sure how to configure the Devise mailer to work with letter_opener.

How do I configure letter_opener so that it will work with the emails sent with Devise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don`t know how it was in Rails 4.x but in Rails 5.1 I did it like so:

1) Install

```
gem 'letter_opener_web', group: :development
```

2) Make your devise model

```
confirmable
```

here`s the link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

3) Add this config

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
```

to

```
config/environments/development.rb
```

in your devise initializer(config/initializers/devise.rb)

```
config.mailer_sender = 'foo@bar.com'
config.mailer        = Devise.mailer
```

4) Do not forget to mount your letter_opener web interface to routes.rb

```
mount LetterOpenerWeb::Engine, at: '/letter_opener' if Rails.env.development?
```

This works pretty nice. Your mails will be available at

```
localhost:3000/letter_opener
```